# Facebook chat reports "not-authorized", although "xmpp_login" is granted

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, xmpp, x-facebook-platform

I am trying to integrate the facebook chat into our mobile Flash/AIR application, and am using [XIFF](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/xiff/) for the XMPP stuff. Of course, I had to modify some files for the newer Facebook API that uses access_token instead of sig and secret.

For those familiar with the xiff/smack API, here is how I establish the connection:

```
XFacebookPlatform.setFacebookSessionValues(AppData.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, AppData.getInstance().getFBSession().accessToken);
XMPPConnection.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", XFacebookPlatform);

var con :XMPPConnection = new XMPPConnection();
con.server = "chat.facebook.com";
con.useAnonymousLogin = true;
con.connect(XMPPConnection.STREAM_TYPE_STANDARD);
```

.

Basically, I get to the point where I answer the challenge with what IMO should be a correct format:

```
var responseMap:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
responseMap.api_key = fb_api_key;
        responseMap.call_id = 0;
        responseMap.method = incomingChallengeMap.method;
        responseMap.nonce = incomingChallengeMap.nonce;
        responseMap.access_token = user_access_token;
        responseMap.v = "1.0";

        var challengeResponse:String = "api_key=" + responseMap.api_key;
        challengeResponse += "&call_id=" + responseMap.call_id;
        challengeResponse += "&method=" + responseMap.method;
        challengeResponse += "&nonce=" + responseMap.nonce;
        challengeResponse += "&access_token=" + responseMap.access_token;
        challengeResponse += "&v=" + responseMap.v;
        challengeResponse = Base64.encode( challengeResponse );
```

.

The response is sent, but as an answer I receive the following:

```
<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
```

This sounds like I did not grant the "xmpp_login", but I did. I checked that via the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), and for the same access_token it shows:

```
{
 "data": [
   {
     "installed": 1,
     "xmpp_login": 1,
     "user_online_presence": 1,
     "friends_online_presence": 1
   }
 ]
}
```

This should be more than enough, I guess.

But still I get the "not-authorized" failure.
Any ideas what went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, the problem was this line:

```
var con :XMPPConnection = new XMPPConnection();
```

Which has to be replaced with this line:

```
var con :XMPPTLSConnection = new XMPPTLSConnection();
```

That's it. The facebook chat only authenticates with a TLS connection.

.

While that does make sense, the error message of

```
<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
```

is **very** misleading here, as it implies that something with the rights would be wrong.